# scroll doesn't work with operations

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this js code for when user scroll reach 0px of bottom, something happen:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    console.log("ok");
      $( ".more" ).trigger( "click" );
   }
});
```

but when i want that event occurred when user scroll distance  of bootm equal to 100px,js code doesn't work, here is that code doesn't work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = ($(document).height())-100;
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == scroll) {
    console.log("ok");
      $( ".more" ).trigger( "click" );
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by updating code as below:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
   console.log("ok");
   $( ".more" ).trigger( "click" );
 }
```

});

Comment: yes,it work but thats buggy,because i use scroll,i must use only equal sign

Comment: Yes, In that case, your code will also work, just scroll very slowly, because it will require to scroll exactly 100px from bottom.